# Can we create feature branch from release branch

Tags: git, github, version-control, gitlab, git-branch

I am practising git these days. I have a query regarding best pratice on creating feature branches. In my project, creating release branches first from develop branch and then creating feature branches from these release branch.

But when I searched in google, I found that feature branches getting branched off from develop branch and then while release time these feature branches gets merged again into develop, and then release branch gets branched off from develop branch.

May I know are we going to face any issues with the approach following in our project, please clear me.

Comment: Technically, you never create any branch from any other branch: you always create a new branch from a *commit*. A branch name simply holds the hash ID of one (1) commit. `git branch new old` means: *Find the commit named by `old`, and then create a new branch name `new` that points to that commit.* You can use a raw hash ID (`git branch new a123456`), or a remote-tracking name (`git branch new origin/something`, or a tag (`git branch new v1.2`), or anything else here: it just has to turn, via `git rev-parse`, into a commit hash ID.

Comment: People build these complicated rules around branch names, and to Git, these rules are all just gibberish, because *Git doesn't actually care about branch names at all*. Git only cares about *commits*. The commits are everything—the branch names just help you (and Git) *find* the commits.

Comment: That said, if performing an elaborate dance ritual while burning the right kind of incense and praying to the right deity helps you use the correct commits, more power to you for doing it that way. What matters to *humans* and what matters to *Git* are completely different things. Just keep it clear in your head that fancy branch-name things are for *humans*, not for Git itself.

Comment: @torek  I agree fancy branch names are only for humans but not to git. But I just want to know normally which is the best practice that we need to follow ie., whether to create feature branch from release branch (or) from develop branch? Kindly re-read my description..

Comment: Personally, I disagree with whichever rule you agree with. :-) Seriously though, read what *I* wrote and you'll see that best practice here is *irrelevant*.

Comment: @torek  I agree whatever you mentioned but I am pretty sure we definitely need to follow some branching strategy in our project. So, May I know which branching strategy is better incase of creating feature branches?

Comment: Which is better, a Fiat Panda or a Fiat 500? Which is better, a VW Golf or a VW Jetta? You'll find people who will argue for one or the other. But in fact no one thing is always better than any other one thing. Don't try to use a recipe to solve a problem for which a recipe doesn't apply.

Comment: @torek so, you saying any approach would be fine? We dont require to follow any branching strategy? I want you to make understand my query more clealry, for eg: we use some design patterns in the code, so that we can write better code and the same functionality can be achieved without using any deisgn patterns as well, but we will face some problems later when we dont apply good design patterns. Similarly my query is : which is better approach to create feature branch? any issue we face later if we try to create feature branch from Release branch..

Comment: @torek I agree someone will say A is better than B and other will say B is better than A. In your opinion, which is better approach to branch off feature branch and why? and why other apporach is not better...

Comment: Anything *that works* is fine. To overstretch the analogy a bit, you wouldn't use a Fiat 500 to carry 10 tons of coal across Australia, for instance: you need a train or really big lorry for that. I'm not really interested in your query though, I'm merely pointing out that there's no one right answer: this sort of thing is *always* a matter of opinion.

Comment: @john a short and sweet answer to your confusion is the best practice is to create a feature branch is from the release branch.
As develop branch is having features that may or may not on a production
and new feature branch should always be a clone of the production

Comment: @RuchitaSheth .. +1 for you. finally, I found someone who is saying the same thing I asked in the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74856769/why-we-use-develop-branch-to-create-feature-branch and got the discouraging answer and -1.

Answer (score 2):

For the branching structure, preferable branching structure is to create a

1. master branch as a production branch
2. create a **staging** branch from master
3. and then create a **develop** branch from **staging** branch
4. and also practice creating all feature branches from **staging** branch
5. And to test all features together in the development environment merge **feature** branchs to **develop** branch

[image]

6. At the time of release, merge feature branch to **staging** branch and then **staging** branch to **master** branch.

[image]

7. After release, delete the **feature** branch.
8. And rebase other **feature** branches with **staging** branch.

[image]